# How do you install and configure 2 different makes of a asterisk dahdi pri card?

Tags: asterisk

Has anyone installed two model makes of dahdi PRI card in one asterisk system. I am trying to install one **sangoma** and another **allo** card... How to install both dahdi drivers ?

Answer (score 0):

You have compare sangoma's dahdi drivers with regular one, get patch file

After that compare allo's drivers(if they are non-standart) with regular one, get patch file.

Simple option is when you have both based on same regular version. If no, you have compare regular versions and create patches difference.

After that you have try apply all 3 patches to lowerest version of regular driver.

If no success, you have hire hi-end developer with linux driver experience to create patch which will include all patches above.

Anyway, seams like no easy way.